# Hours between runs in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

How do I show how many hour and minutes are between a Startdate_time and Enddate_time in MS Access? A run for a limo company could end on the next day in the early AM hours and start the time before. Do I use two separate fileds at the table level, like [StartDate] [StartTime]? I am lost ;(

Answer (score 1):

Access VBA has a built-in function called [`DateDiff`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

`DateDiff("n", StartDateTime, EndDateTime)` will show you the difference in minutes between two `Date` values.
*(which contain date **and** time, as already said by Burkhard in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32424953/6884))*

You can either call `DateDiff` directly in a query to get the difference in minutes.
Or, if you want to display something like "1:15 hours", you can wrap it in a function like this:

```
Public Function DateDiffHours(StartDateTime As Date, EndDatetime As Date) As String

    Dim Minutes As Integer

    Minutes = DateDiff("n", StartDateTime, EndDatetime)
    DateDiffHours = Fix(Minutes / 60) & ":" & Right("00" & Minutes Mod 60, 2) & " hours"

End Function
```

Comment: DateDiff is the best solution to extract BY FAR

Answer (score 1):

It can be done a lot simpler using direct calculation:

```
HoursMinutes = Format(1 + Enddate_time - Startdate_time, "h:nn")
```

or, if you wish the true date value for your textbox:

```
Me!txtRunTime.Value = CDate(1 + Enddate_time - Startdate_time)
```

Then apply the format to this as you like, for example: `h:nn`

Answer (score 0):

A Date field contains as well days and time. You need a StartDate and an EndDate.

To calculate the days hours and minutes a vb module containing following functions:

```
Public Function CountDays(EndDate, StartDate)
    CountDays = Fix(EndDate - StartDate)
End Function

Public Function HourPart(EndDate, StartDate)
    HourPart = Fix(((EndDate - StartDate) - CountDays(EndDate, StartDate)) * 24)
End Function

Function RemainHour(EndDate, StartDate)
    RemainHour = ((EndDate - StartDate) - CountDays(EndDate, StartDate)) * 24 - HourPart(EndDate, StartDate)
End Function

Public Function MinPart(EndDate, StartDate)
    MinPart = Round(RemainHour(EndDate, StartDate) * 60)
End Function
```

Use this functions in a query. Instead of a field name enter e.E `Duration_Days: countdays([EndDate];[StartDate])` or 
`Duration_hours: hourpart([EndDate];[StartDate])` or 
`Duration_minutes: Minpart([EndDate];[StartDate])`

I hope this was a bit helpful and not too complicated.